# reverse engineer existing relation db in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have an existing relational database (sql server), which I would like to use to create an entity relational diagram from in enterprise architect. I came across [this](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.0/projects_and_teams/connecttosqlserver.html) but am not sure whether this is the right approach to achieve what I described above (I get lots of error messages). Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the wrong page. The page you mentioned is a description on how to create an EA repository on SQL Server.

You have to reverse engineer the database from ODBC. See this [page in the help](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.0/database_engineering/importdatabaseschemafromod.html)

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look.